# Server multiple clients

Tags: java

If there is a posibility, I need someone to explain two another error!!!
I want to send an object to multiple custumer (client) but there is an errors when I execute it!
the first is : Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ClientServer.Master$Worker.send(Master.java:177)

the second is : java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)

```
     public void run() {
        for (int k = 0; k < MAX_IT; k++) {            
            ServerData C = new ServerData(getSousPop(ID), problem);
            try {
                send(C);// here is the first
                Object receiveRequest = receive();
                System.out.println("Recept");
                if(receiveRequest instanceof ClientData){
                    Population pop = ((ClientData)receiveRequest).getPop();
                    LocalePop = pop.clone();
                    SetReady(ID, true);....
```

This is the worker constructer

```
     public Worker(int ID) {
        this.ID = ID;
        try {
            soc = new Socket(IP[ID], ports[ID]);// and the second is here
            in = new ObjectInputStream(soc.getInputStream());
            out  = new ObjectOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Master.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Master.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } 
        start();
    }
```

Comment: Could you post the code of the Worker class please (at least its constructor) ? The snippet given here is not enough to help you.

Comment: Please post the `main` entry and `Worker` class.

Comment: It's traditional to include the stack trace.

Comment: From the looks of it, if `Worker` extends `Thread` and you call `start` in the constructor, there might be a chance that `Thread` is not correctly initialized and thus in an illegal state? If so, try creating the worker and then calling start separately or make worker a composite.

Comment: You call start two times, one in the constructor the other one in lunch method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `start` method two times in the same instance, which throws `IllegalThreadStateException` the second time.

1. One in `lunch` method
2. Other `start` call inside the constructor

---

```
for(int i = 0; i < IP.length; i++) {
    workers[i] = new Worker(i);
}
```

This will call the `Worker` constructor, which starts the thread too:

```
 public Worker(int ID) {
    this.ID = ID;
    [...]
    start();
}
```

This

```
for(int i = 0; i < IP.length; i++) {
    workers[i].start();
}
```

will re-iterate over threads, and start them again (which fails with the `IllegalThreadStateException`).

Remove the `start` call in the constructor, or the `for` cycle.

Comment: I don't understand what you said, you are asking me if you can edit this question to ask something different? Then the answer is not, accept this answer if it solved your problem and create a different one. (it will helps you to get more views too since it's already 1 hour old) (and it's the correct thing to do anyway)

Comment: sorry, but you didn't understand me, your answer is helped me but i found another problem, this is all what i mean, I have to wait two days to ask another one